# Use a for loop in Matlab with increments of 15

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, increment

I'm very new to matlab and I have to use a for loop with increments of 15 for a coordinate point.

I've tried

```
for theta = 0; and(theta <= 360, theta >= 0)
theta +15;
end
```

and

```
theta = 0;
   for theta = [0:360];
       theta = theta+15;
   end
```

the second one is the closes ive gotten to making it work but it still goes over 360, the first seems to make more sense but it gives me an error saying theta was previously used as a variable.

```
y12 = sind(theta) + cosd(theta);
y1 = sind(theta);
y2=cosd(theta);
plot(theta,y12)
plot(theta,y1)
plot(theta,y2)
title 'Project 7D - 3 curves(0-2*pi)'
xlabel 'Angle in Radian'
ylabel 'Function Value'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't actually need a loop.

```
theta=0:15:360;

y12 = sind(theta) + cosd(theta);
y1 = sind(theta);
y2 = cosd(theta);

hold all;
plot(theta,y12)
plot(theta,y1)
plot(theta,y2)
title 'Project 7D - 3 curves(0-2*pi)'
xlabel 'Angle in Radian'
ylabel 'Function Value'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for theta=0:15:360
     y12 = sind(theta) + cosd(theta);
     y1 = sind(theta);
     y2=cosd(theta);
     hold all;
     plot(theta,y12)
     plot(theta,y1)
     plot(theta,y2)
     title 'Project 7D - 3 curves(0-2*pi)'
     xlabel 'Angle in Radian'
     ylabel 'Function Value'
    end
```

`0:15:360` starts at 0 and increments 15 each time and ends at 360

Comment: its only using 360 as a value when i plug it in a plot.

Comment: i added it in the main body